# Get Sundays For a given month Date in a function SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I am facing a problem. I want to get no of sunday in a month using a function although i have achieved a similar result using a procedure but i need to call that function in my select query to return result for each select. My code for the procedure is given

```
    create proc [dbo].[getSundaysandSaturdays]
(
    @Year int=2016,
    @Month int=11,
    @fdays as int output
)
as
begin
    ;with dates as
    (
        select dateadd(month,@month-1,dateadd(year,@year-1900,0)) as StartDate
        union all
        select startdate + 1 from dates where month(startdate+1) = @Month
    )
    select @fdays=count(*) from dates where datediff(dd,0,startdate)%7 in (4)
    return @fdays
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed like below and also modified logic required to find sunday's by using `datepart`  function.  If you want to return saturday's count also then add it in where clause.

```
 create function [dbo].[getSundaysandSaturdays]
    (
        @Year int,
        @Month int

    ) 
    RETURNS int
    as 
    begin
    declare     @fdays int 
        ;with dates as
        (
            select dateadd(month,@month-1,dateadd(year,@year-1900,0)) as StartDate
            union all
            select startdate + 1 from dates where month(startdate+1) = @Month
        )
        select @fdays=count(*) from dates where datepart(dw,StartDate) =1
      return @fdays
      end
```

And Call function like below

```
  select  dbo.[getSundaysandSaturdays](2015,11)
```

Comment: @Kamran my answer returns the same result but execute in less than 1/30 the time of this solution (tested by calling the function 43524 times).

Answer (score 3):

Your current issue is that you can't call a stored procedure from a select. You need a function for that. Here is a working function.

Another issue - avoid making recursive sql to count the sundays in a month. This "simple" expression will calculate the sundays in a month.

```
CREATE function f_count_sundays
(
  @Year int,
  @Month int
) returns int
BEGIN
DECLARE @x date = dateadd(month,@month-1+(@year-1900)*12,6)
RETURN datediff(d, dateadd(d,datediff(d,-1,@x)/7*7,-1),dateadd(m,1,@x))/7
END

go

SELECT dbo.f_count_sundays(2016,10)
```

Result:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
select * from f_table_date('20090601', '20090630')
where weekdayname ='sun'
```

Comment: My procedure works fine i just want the code to convert it into a function

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider creating a Date table and then querying that as it would be a better long-term solution over what you are attempting to do, as you could count ANY day of the month, faster and more eloquently than an SQL Function.

```
SELECT Count(0) 
FROM dimDate 
WHERE 
DayName = 'Sunday'
AND [CalendarYear] = 2016
AND [CalendarMonth] = 'May' 
-- Or you could use a '03' if you preferred.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [DBO].[UDF_getSundaysandSaturdays] 
(
    @Year int,
    @Month int,
    @Day int  --5 for Sat & 6 for Sun
    )
RETURNS INT
as
begin
DECLARE @DayCount INT
    ;with dates as
    (
        select dateadd(month,@month-1,dateadd(year,@year-1900,0)) as StartDate
        union all
        select startdate + 1 from dates where month(startdate+1) = @Month
    )

    SELECT @DayCount=(select count(*) from dates where datediff(dd,0,startdate)%7 in (@Day))
    RETURN @DayCount
end
```

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your source code. If you could add some descriptive text, your answer would be much more better to read.