# How can I count how many Sundays is in one month in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, count, dayofweek, days

Here is just one Sunday, but I can't count how many Sundays are in one month :

```
select dateadd(dd, 8 - datepart(dw, '2019-11-01'), '2019-11-01')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742687/get-sundays-for-a-given-month-date-in-a-function-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Sundays For a given month Date in a function SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742687/get-sundays-for-a-given-month-date-in-a-function-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Updated the Code to more flexible

```
Declare @Month Bigint, @Year Bigint, @DayName VARCHAR(10) = 'Thursday'
Declare @date date
SET @Year = 2024
SET @Month = 2
SET @date = CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + (CASE WHEN @Month > 9 THEN CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(2)) ELSE '0' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(2)) END)  +'-01'
Declare @CountDays int = 0
while DATEPART(Month,@date) = @Month
Begin
    --Select DATEPART(DAY,@date);
    --Select DATEPART( WEEKDAY, @DATE )
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(20)

    SELECT  @Name = CASE ( DATEPART(dw, @Date) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7
                         WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
                         WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
                         WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
                         WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
                         WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
                         WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
                         WHEN 0 THEN 'Saturday'
                       END 
    If @Name = @DayName
    Begin
        --Insert Data Into Your Table
        --Select @date
        SET @CountDays = @CountDays + 1
    End
    
    Set @date = DATEADD(Day, 1, @date); 
End

SELECT @CountDays
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @MONTH as DATE = '20191225';   --any date in the month


;WITH THEMONTH AS (SELECT DATEADD(day,1 - DAY(@MONTH) , @MONTH) AS x
   UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(day,1, x) FROM THEMONTH WHERE MONTH(DATEADD(day,1, x)) = MONTH(x))

             select count(*) from THEMONTH  WHERE  DATENAME(weekday, x)  ='sunday';
```

I subtracted back to the first of whatever month it is in the date by subtracting DAY - 1 days.

I used a recursive CTE to add days until the next day is outside the current month

I then counted the DATENAME Sunday in my set of data

Answer (score 2):

That's simple, because of the way WW works in DATEDIFF 
(note: startdate is non-inclusive, thus -1).

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(ww, CAST('20081228' AS datetime)-1, '20090131') AS NumOfSundays
```

That is

```
DATEDIFF(ww, @dt1-1, @dt2)
```

To get the start and end of a month (of current_timestamp in this example):

```
SELECT 
     DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0) AS StartOfMonth
    ,EOMONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS EndOfMonth
```

Note: 
WW does NOT return the number of whole weeks, but in fact it really returns number of sundays (except if the first date is sunday).

And -1 works because DATETIME is castable to float, where the integer part is the number of days since 1900/01/01. The part behind the comma is the time as fraction of 24h.

From the [documentation of Access for Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datediff-function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f), which uses the same datediff-function:

> If interval is Week ("ww"), however, the DateDiff function returns the
> number of calendar weeks between the two dates. It counts the number
> of Sundays between date1 and date2. DateDiff counts date2 if it falls
> on a Sunday; but it doesn't count date1, even if it does fall on a
> Sunday.

e.g.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
         0 AS i 
        ,DATEADD(MONTH, 0, '20220101') AS StartOfMonth 
        ,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 0, '20220101')) AS EndOfMonth 
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, 0, '20220101')) AS Month 
        ,2022 AS Year 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CTE.i +1 AS i 
        ,DATEADD(MONTH, CTE.i+1, '20220101') AS Start
        ,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, CTE.i+1, '20220101')) AS EndOfMonth 
        ,DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, CTE.i+1, '20220101')) AS Month  
        ,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, CTE.i+1, '20220101')) AS Year
    FROM CTE WHERE CTE.i < 30
)
SELECT 
     StartOfMonth 
    ,EndOfMonth 
    ,Month + ' ' + CAST(Year AS nvarchar(20)) AS DateName 
    ,DATEDIFF(ww, StartOfMonth-1, EndOfMonth) AS NumOfSundays 
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Your calculation does not return the expected result. The formula is way more complicated

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @Month Bigint
Set @Month =11
Declare @date date;
Set @date='2011-11-01'

while DATEPART(Month,@date)=@Month
Begin
    --Select DATEPART(DAY,@date);
    --Select DATEPART( WEEKDAY, @DATE )
    DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(20)

    SELECT  @Name = CASE ( DATEPART(dw, @Date) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7
                         WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday'
                         WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday'
                         WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
                         WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
                         WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday'
                         WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday'
                         WHEN 0 THEN 'Saturday'
                       END 
    If @Name='Sunday'
    Begin
        
        --Insert Data Into Your Table
        Select @date
    End
    
    Set @date=DATEADD(Day,1,@date); 
End
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.